# How to understand this Javadoc "reference not found" error?

Tags: java, javadoc

TLDR: question proper at the bottom.

Consider a scenario like this:

**a/A.java**

```
package a;

/** A class designed for inheritance. */
public class A {

  /** An amazing enum! */
  protected enum AEnum {
    /** A wonderful value. */
    A1,
    /** A marvellous value. */
    A2
  }

  /**
   * Subclasses can call this constructor.
   *
   * @param ae may very well be {@link AEnum#A1}!
   */
  protected A(AEnum ae) { }

};
```

**b/B.java**

```
package b;
import a.A;

/** My second class, so happy! */
public class B {

  /**
   * A constructor of {@link B}, takes an instance of {@link A}.
   * Maybe I want to say that something depends on whether
   * {@code aInstance} was constructed with {@link a.A.AEnum#A1}?
   *
   * @param aInstance (hmm, what could {@code aInstance} be? ;-)
   */
  public B(A aInstance) { }

};
```

Javadoc complains about this line:

```
src/b/B.java:10: error: reference not found
   * {@code aInstance} was constructed with {@link a.A.AEnum#A1}?
                                                   ^
```

but in the compiled HTML, creates a proper link to the corresponding `enum` value anyway. I am confused about this error, why report the reference as "not found" when it's found all right?

Now of course it's strange to want to refer to the `protected` element my `B` has no access to, but this is not code, just a documentation. I believe there are situations where it is justifiable. I ran into this when defining an unchecked exception (keeping all exceptions in a separate package) and explaining that it would be thrown if a `protected` constructor of the original class was called with some particular setting and the contract violated. I read [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=171) that I should not put a `@throw` in the constructor's doc, so where else to describe the error condition than in the exception?

*Am I right that rather than a malformed `@link` or something this error is "just" a warning about an access violation? Or should something be formatted differently? Is this expected behaviour?*